# jQuery don't show hidden element when other element is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to hide `p element` and show it when second tabpanel is active. I have a panel in bootstrap like this:

```
<div id="Mobile-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"><h2>Do You have a smartphone ?</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="mobile-panel" role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" id="smartphone-on" class="active"><a href="#smart-yes" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Yes</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" id="smartphone-off" ><a href="#smart-no" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">No</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="smart-yes">

        <div class="smart-item 1">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="smart-item 2">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

        <div class="smart-item 3">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

        <div class="smart-item 4">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="smart-no">

        <div class="smart-item 1">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

        <div class="smart-item 2">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

        <div class="smart-item 3">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

        <div class="smart-item 4">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>sit dolor amet</p>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p id="menu-legend">*not available</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added to footer.php javascript code, because I want to show paragraph with `id="menu-legend"` ,when panel second is active `(li#smartphone-off)`, but it's not working. 
jQuery library is loading - when i added below only `$("#menu-legend").hide();` -it's working good. Where's the problem ?

```
<?php
    }
    if ($pagename == "New smartphones - Landin Page"){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#menu-legend").hide();

if ($("smartphone-off").hasClass("active")){

    $("#menu-legend").show();
};

</script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: you forget # beside smartphone-off in if statemenet  or that's a wrong typo

Comment: `$(function () { ... put your code here ...});` - you need to wait till document is loaded. and the comment above ;)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I replaced it, and still no effects :(

Comment: <li role="presentation" id="smartphone-off" > has no class active

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef It have this class when I click on second tabpanel

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/kezt4qff/

Comment: logically you have something wrong in your code arrangement .. and posted code check when document load .. so how it can check your element has class or not .. for sure when document load  your element hasn't class active

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){ //put your code inside document ready
    $("#menu-legend").hide();

    if ($("#smartphone-off").hasClass("active")){    //add # to smartphone-off selector
        $("#menu-legend").show();
    };
});
```

Comment: Ehh... It's not working

But only $("#menu-legend").hide(); working good. Just woow.

Comment: check if #smartphone-off has "active" class

Comment: Yes, it's active, but <p> is still hidden.

Comment: Where are you setting the active class? Maybe you are setting the class after .hasClass("active") call

Comment: You are right. I change classes after this by click on second tabpanel, but what can I do to show and hide this element by changing tabpanels ?